# How to update two tables using id from one table to another?

Tags: mysql, node.js, join, primary-key, insert-update

I am writing a Node JS script, what I want to use for updating 2 tables from a remote database. The script does the following so far:

- It connects to the remote database, selects the new values since a given time.
- It connects to the local database, inserts or updates the new/edited rows to table A.
- Updates or inserts new rows to the second table using id from table A as primary key.
  I've done task 1 and 2.

My code so far:

```
let mysql = require('mysql');

let con = mysql.createConnection({ //Server A
    host: "192.168.1.10",
    user: "user1",
    password: "pswd1",
    database: "a_database"
});

let con2 = mysql.createConnection({ //Server B
    host: "192.168.1.11",
    user: "user2",
    password: "pswd2",
    database: "b_database"
});

let sqlSelectDatabaseA = "SELECT uid,name,email,city,street,number FROM users \n" +
    "WHERE uid IN (SELECT DISTINCT u.uid FROM logs l INNER JOIN users u ON l.id = u.uid ORDER BY uid;";

let sqlSelectId = "SELECT max(id) AS ID FROM addresses";

let sqlInsertUsers = "INSERT INTO users (username,email,mobile,city,street,client_number,contactAddress) VALUES ? ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE \n" +
"username=VALUES(username),email=VALUES(email),mobile=VALUES(mobile),city=VALUES(city),street=VALUES(street);"; //I've solved the insert/update in this sql command
let sqlInsertAddresses = "INSERT INTO addresses (country,city,street,number) VALUES ?"; //Here I would need update too

con.connect(async function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    con.query(sqlSelectDatabaseA, function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        con2.connect(function(err) {
            if (err) throw err;
            con2.query(sqlSelectId, function (err, result2) {
                if (err) throw err;
                let addressId = result2[0].ID;
                let values1 = [];
                let values2 = [];
                for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                    addressId++;
                    values1[i] = [result[i].city,result[i].street,result[i].number];
                    values2[i] = [result[i].name,result[i].email,result[i].city,result[i].street + ' ' + result[i].number,result[i].uid,++addressId];
                }
                con2.query(sqlInsertAddresses, [values1], function (err, result3) {
                    if (err)
                        throw err;
                    console.log("Number of records inserted/updated in addresses table : " + result3.affectedRows); //Now I only insert the addresses, don't check them if they exist, this would be the task, to achieve a check if it exists or not, if exists, update it, if not, insert it
                    con2.query(sqlInsertUsers, [values2], function (err, result4) {
                        if (err) throw err;
                        console.log("Number of records inserted/updated in users table: " + result4.affectedRows);
                        con.end();
                        con2.end();
                    });
                });

            });

        });
    });
});
```

I would like to find a solution for using the value at users.contactAddress as a PRIMARY KEY on the addresses table. If a record with the given primary key exists, it only updates the values, if doesn't, inserts a new record.

If it's possible, without new sql commands. But if there is no other way, that will do too.

Example:

- in the logs table a new row appeared, it looks like |logId|userId|
- the script uses this row's userId, connects to database A, gets the new values from the users table
- using the values from database A the script inserts or updates the users table in database B
- depending on if an update or an insert happened, it adds a row to addresses table, or updates the values in the addresses table where the id (PRIMARY KEY) equals to the updates users record's contactAddress field

[Database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hG2o.png)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS usersA (
  `uid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `mobile` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `street` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `number` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`uid`)
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS logsA (
  `logId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userId` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`logId`)
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS addressesB (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `city` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `street` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `buildingNumber` varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS usersB (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `mobile` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `street` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `klient_number` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `contactAddress` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `klient_number` (`klient_number`)
);
INSERT INTO usersA (username,email,mobile,city,street,number) VALUES("John Smith", "john.smith@gmail.com", "0000", "city", "street", 15);
INSERT INTO usersA (username,email,mobile,city,street,number) VALUES("Kate Smith", "kate.smith@gmail.com", "0000", "city_updated", "street1", 11);
INSERT INTO usersA (username,email,mobile,city,street,number) VALUES("Will Smith", "will.smith@gmail.com", "0000", "city2", "street2", 6);
INSERT INTO usersB (username,email,mobile,city,street,klient_number, contactAddress) VALUES("John Smith", "john.smith@gmail.com", "0000", "city", "street 15", 1, 1);
INSERT INTO usersB (username,email,mobile,city,street,klient_number, contactAddress) VALUES("Kate Smith", "kate.smith@gmail.com", "0000", "city 1", "street1 11", 2, 2);
INSERT INTO addressesB (city, street, buildingNumber) VALUES ("city", "street", "15");
INSERT INTO addressesB (city, street, buildingNumber) VALUES ("city 1", "street1", "11");
INSERT INTO logsA (userId) VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO logsA (userId) VALUES (3);
```

Desired result: the script selects users from usersA table, checks users in usersB table. If there is a record with the same klient_number as the PRIMARY KEY in usersA table (so, uid), then it updates, else it inserts. It does the same in addresses table.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Basically what I have is a users table and an addresses table. Users table has a column, named contactAddress, what refers to the addresses table's PRIMARY KEY, a.k.a. the ID field. So my task would be to check if either users.contactAddress is null or is equal to a non-existent addresses ID.

Comment: Added an example, including the desired result.

Comment: Added the database structure in image, I hope it helps. Or if I misunderstood something, correct me.

Comment: I am using a more theoretical approach. But since you really want to do your approach, there you go, I added the create and insert statements, stated in the first paragraph, I have no idea how to define sql wise the desired data, so I can only provide you a theoretical approach. And I have already included my best efforts (based on paragraph 3), see the code.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're after something like this:

```
INSERT INTO usersB 
(username
,mobile
,email
,city
,street
,klient_number) 
SELECT username
     , mobile
     , email
     , city
     , CONCAT_WS(' ',street,number)
     , uid 
  FROM usersA a 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY 
UPDATE username = a.username
     , mobile = a.mobile
     , email = a.email
     , city = a.city
     , street = CONCAT_WS(' ',a.street,a.number)
     , klient_number = a.uid;

Query OK, 3 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 1  Warnings: 0

SELECT * FROM usersB;
+----+------------+--------+----------------------+--------------+------------+---------------+----------------+
| id | username   | mobile | email                | city         | street     | klient_number | contactAddress |
+----+------------+--------+----------------------+--------------+------------+---------------+----------------+
|  1 | John Smith | 0000   | john.smith@gmail.com | city         | street 15  |             1 |              1 |
|  2 | Kate Smith | 0000   | kate.smith@gmail.com | city_updated | street1 11 |             2 |              2 |
|  3 | Will Smith | 0000   | will.smith@gmail.com | city2        | street2 6  |             3 |              0 |
+----+------------+--------+----------------------+--------------+------------+---------------+----------------+
```

Comment: If you look at my code, I have something similar as you wrote. The only difference is, that as I mentioned, the two databases are on different servers, so I need to use two different mysql connections, so I cannot use only one sql script. My question is more focused on the addresses table. How can I update or insert into the addresses table too, as you did with the usersB table. (using the contactAddress value from usersB).

Comment: @Peter Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please act on all the comments. Please give a [mre]--which includes cut & paste & runnable code in your post. Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. See [ask], [help], [meta] & [meta.se].

Comment: @philipxy I've updated my current code, it should be runnable, that's my entire progress so far. I've also put comments in the code, expressing what would I like to achieve. I hope it fits the requirements now.